# Integrating TortoiseSVN commits with Jira Issues

Tags: issue-tracker, subversion

We're using [TortoiseSVN v1.8.7](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to make commits to Subversion.
We're also using [Jira v6.3.1](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) for issue mangagment.

When we work on a particular issue in SVN, we can use smart commits to associate those changes with the issues

> **i.e.** "CM-23: adding new class for awesome-sauce!"

It would be nice if developers could see a list of open issues assigned to them when adding the commit message so they don't accidentally fat finger the ID.

TortoiseSVN has an [interface for enabling plugins with issues trackers](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ibugtraqprovider.html). They even list some of the [available implementations](http://tortoisesvn.net/issuetrackerplugins.html)

But all the projects I've found look like they're no longer being developed or for older versions of JIRA.

- [Atlassian Jira](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34578/)
- [TortoiseSVN Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.plugins.TortoiseSVN)
- [JiraSVN](http://csharptest.net/projects/jirasvn/)
- [Integration of JIRA with TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8641950/1366033)

**Q**: *Are there any modern tools to help integrate Jira and TortoiseSVN?*